# Nested Wordpress Post Object loops with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking to display a post object inside another post object.

This is useful to display content (that is containing post objects) from one page on another.

I expect this could be something that is not working with the repeated wp_reset_postdata.

Thankful for any ideas and suggestions.

```
<?php $post_object = get_sub_field('first-loop');
if( $post_object ): 
    $post = $post_object;
    setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

        <?php $post_object = get_sub_field('second-loop');
        if( $post_object ): 
            $post = $post_object;
            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

                <!-- advanded custom fields -->

            <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you share what field type you have selected for `first-loop` and `second-loop` in the backend? also what is the return format for both of these fields?

Comment: @saqib-amin field type for `first-loop` is Post Object and return format is Post Object. The same goes for  the `second-loop`. Thank you

Comment: since you are using `get_sub_field` there has to be a parent `repeater` field, can you share that field's name too?

Comment: This is the code in which the mentioned snipped is:

`<?php if( have_rows('element') ):
    while ( have_rows('element') ) : the_row(); ?>

 <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'upcomming-events' ): ?>



 <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from the Advanced Custom Fields support (thank you Patrick!) and the solution is as follows. This is a loop on a single-book [custom post] that contains a custom field which is a post-object that fetches content from another a custom post (seller) that lists a series of post-objects (books).

```
<?php  $post_object = get_field('post-object'); 
if( $post_object->ID ): ?>
        post-object title: <?php echo $post_object->post_title; ?>
        <?php if( have_rows('books', $post_object->ID) ):?>
            <?php while ( have_rows('books', $post_object->ID) ) : the_row();?>
                <?php  $book = get_sub_field('book');
                if( $book->ID ): 
                ?>
                Title: <?php echo($book->post_title); ?>
                <?php echo($book->cover ); ?>
                <?php $image = get_field('cover' , $book);
                if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['medium']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?> 
            <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
<?php $post_object = get_sub_field('first-loop');
if( $post_object ): 
    $post1 = $post_object; // this should be post object not id, if id then use get_post function and use post object.
    setup_postdata( $post1 ); ?>

        <?php $post_object = get_sub_field('second-loop');
        if( $post_object ): 
            $post2 = $post_object;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            setup_postdata( $post2 ); ?>

                <!-- advanded custom fields -->

            <?php wp_reset_postdata();
            setup_postdata( $post1 ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responce @jaydip !

However, it seems that I'm not allowed to change $post to $post1. When I do, links for example are showing the current page (index) and not the post-id page (events).

`<?php $post_object = get_sub_field('page-link');
if( $post_object ): 
    $post1 = $post_object; // this should be post object not id, if id then use get_post function and use post object.
    setup_postdata( $post1 ); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: @ÅsmundSollihøgda You can create double variables, like add `$post = $post1` and use `$post1` to set post data and again change `$post` variable with new post data when you set it.

Comment: Thank you again for the quick feedback. I tried to implement your suggestion without luck. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

`<?php $post_object = get_sub_field('page-link');
if( $post_object ): 
 $post = $post1;
    $post1 = $post_object;
    setup_postdata( $post1 ); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif; ?>`